# How to add new element to const char ** array

Tags: c

What's up?
I am very interested in the question of how to add a new element to my array

```
uint32 glfw_extension_count = 0;
const char** glfw_extensions;
glfw_extensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfw_extension_count);

return glfw_extensions;
```

I just need add to 'glfw_extensions' VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user have plenty of online resource to learn and solve this issue.

Comment: Understand that `char**` has absolutely nothing to do with an array. It is a *single-pointer* to another *pointer*. It points to an allocated block of pointers. You then allocate storage for blocks of characters assigning the beginning address to your next available pointer in turn. You can *Simulate* 2D array *indexing*, but there is no array involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (great!) [documentation says](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__vulkan.html#ga1abcbe61033958f22f63ef82008874b1):

> **Pointer lifetime**
>
> The returned array is allocated and freed by GLFW. You should not free it yourself. It is guaranteed to be valid only until the library is terminated.

So clearly you can't do the necessary re-allocation. So you must allocate a new array, copy the data in, and then append your additional entry. I would assume that you can safely copy the string pointers themselves, didn't see a lot of discussion about that in the documentation page so it might need further verification.